# strange behaviour in select option:selected

Tags: jquery

I have a few select options boxes on one page, I'm trying to get the value and text of the selected options and insert them into hidden fields, if I select the first one only(first time after page reload)it doesn't work, but if I select the first one and the second one after page reload it works,

to make it work I have to first select an option from the second select box and all will work.

here's a link to the site.
 http://www.snappy-pizza.net/sides.php

any help would be appreciated.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="MIXED SALAD" />
    <select class="select" name="select3" id="select3">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1.99">1</option>
        <option value="1.99">2</option>
        <option value="1.99">3</option>
        <option value="1.99">4</option>
        <option value="1.99">5</option>
        <option value="1.99">6</option>
        <option value="1.99">7</option>
        <option value="1.99">8</option>
    </select>
</form>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="Onion Rings" />
    <select class="select" name="select" id="select">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1.99">1</option>
        <option value="1.99">2</option>
        <option value="1.99">3</option>
        <option value="1.99">4</option>
        <option value="1.99">5</option>
        <option value="1.99">6</option>
        <option value="1.99">7</option>
        <option value="1.99">8</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {

        $('#my-add-button-sides').click(function () {
            var qty = [];
            var price = [];
            var items_names = [];
            var final_price = 0;

            $('.select option:selected').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if (($this.text()) > 0) {
                    qty.push($this.text());
                    price.push($this.val());
                    items_names.push($this.parent().prev('input:hidden').val());
                }
                $this.attr('selected', '');
            });

            var total_price = $.map(qty, function (n, i) {
                return n * price[i];
            });

            $.each(total_price, function () {
                final_price += this;
            });

            var qty_items = $.map(qty, function (n, i) {
                return n + "--" + items_names[i];
            });

            var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000) + 200);
            $('input[name=my-item-id]').val(randomNumber);
            $('input[name=my-item-name]').val(qty_items.join('\n'));
            $('input[name=my-item-price]').val(final_price);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code and I have a final_price result even if only the first select box is used. I select the first box value 1 and get 1.99 response. Check your example.

Update
PizzaPrice is not defined is the error I get.
Try to put the first block of code also in the $(function() {} which is a wrapper for the ready() function. Your code doesnt have acces to PizzaPrice variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for testing the code.but if you follow the link http://www.snappy-pizza.net/sides.php
and just select 1 from the first select box nothing will be added to the cart but you choose the second one first, all of them will work.

Comment: the problem still exist, one thing I don't understand is that if I first choose the second select box(i.e onion rings) and then select sth else, everything would work.

Comment: My select options are in a form tag inside a <td> tag, do you thing that can cause the problem. thanks

Comment: Your example is working . Is adding when clicking add. Is adding the same thing all over, but this is another thing. There are several things that seem to be still under development here.